# Shell script: Crontab does not execute the shell script if I am calling another shell script from that script

Tags: cron

I have one runner shell script where I have defined other shell scripts to execute in one go. While running manually it is working fine. But When I am running through crontab it does not trigger.

I also saw that if I add /bin/bash Script.sh then it works. But It is quite complex to add adding `/bin/bash` before every script as some scripts are also calling other scripts internally?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation for your issues is the fact that Cron tends to run stuff with `/bin/sh` by default, so you do not have all BASH power available.

To combat this, change the command in the cron file from `/a/b/script.sh` to `/bin/bash /a/b/script.sh` so your top level script starts out as bash. Also recommended would be to put a `#!` ([shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))) on the beginning of all your script files

Comment: This I had already tried. Problem is not that crontab is not executing the script - It executes but it stops triggering if the Calling script contains other scripts to run.